# Index Flux (Spring Webflux) to ElasticSearch using ElasticSearch-Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-webflux

*What I am trying to achieve:*

1 - From a Flux (Spring Webflux, Reactor)

2 - Index/Save/Insert each element of the flux inside ElasticSearch, using the **bulk** API
(not one by one) of elasticsearch-java https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html#_indexing_application_objects (not using spring data elasticsearch)

3 - **Retain the flux** from step 2 in order to do some further processing

*What did I try:*

```
@Service
public final class SomeService implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient;

    @Override
    public void run(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Flux<Product> productFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map(i -> new Product(LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC), String.valueOf(i))); //Actual would be an aggresive flux from Kafka or http
        Flux<Product> savedFlux = saveAll(productFlux);
        Flux<CompletedProduct> completedProductFlux = savedFlux.map(oneSavedProduct -> toOneCompletedProduct(oneSavedProduct)); //some kind of post processing which happens after it is saved
        completedProductFlux.subscribe();
    }

    private Flux<Product> saveAll(Flux<Product> productFlux) throws IOException {
        BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();
        for (Product product : productFlux.toIterable()) { // changed here
            br.operations(op -> op
                    .index(idx -> idx
                            .index("products")
                            .document(product)
                    )
            );
        }
        BulkResponse result = elasticsearchClient.bulk(br.build());
        System.out.println("I do care about the response " + result.ingestTook());
        if (result.errors()) {
            System.out.println("I do care about the response Bulk had errors");
            for (BulkResponseItem item: result.items()) {
                if (item.error() != null) {
                    System.out.println(item.error().reason());
                }
            }
        }
        return productFlux;
    }

    private CompletedProduct toOneCompletedProduct(Product oneSavedProduct) {
        return // transform a product to a completed product AFTER saving to elasticsearch;
    }

}
```

*Note:*

The flux from step 1 would be coming from kafka or http, it is an aggressive flux

For step 2, I do care about the response (doing some logging in case of errors)

*Issue:*

With the above code, I am able to generate the flux of products, but this is not inserting/saving/indexing anything inside elasticsearch.

*Question:*

How to save all the elements from the flux using the bulk api of elasticsearch-java within a reactor pipeline of reactor spring webflux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have written seems to be trying to consume a [`Flux`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) as an `Iterable`, which might be the reason it is not working as expected.

In your case, you are trying to use the `toIterable` method from the `Flux` API to convert a `Flux` into an `Iterable`. This is not recommended because (reading "[Reactor Core Features](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/17ac6f44e73e8a62f5c28fe2af196006c7e6abf4/docs/asciidoc/coreFeatures.adoc#L234)") `Flux` is designed to be non-blocking and backpressure-aware, while `Iterable` is a blocking API. This could be the reason why the code is not indexing data into Elasticsearch.

The issue you are facing in your code seems to be related to this blocking operation. In your `saveAll()` method, you are transforming the `Flux` into an `Iterable` and then trying to perform a bulk indexing operation on the products.
However, because `Flux.toIterable()` is a blocking operation and the bulk indexing operation is asynchronous, this might not be working as expected.

Instead of consuming a `Flux` as an `Iterable`, you should use the `Flux` API to chain operations together in a non-blocking way. In this case, you could use the [`collectList` method](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#collectList--) to buffer all the elements of the `Flux` into a `List`, then use the `map` method to transform the `List` into a `BulkRequest`.

[image: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/doc-files/marbles/collectList.svg]

For example:

```java
private Flux<Product> saveAll(Flux<Product> productFlux) {
    return productFlux.collectList().flatMap(products -> {
        BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();
        for (Product product : products) {
            br.operations(op -> op
                    .index(idx -> idx
                            .index("products")
                            .document(product)
                    )
            );
        }
        return Mono.just(br.build());
    }).flatMap(bulkRequest -> {
        try {
            BulkResponse result = elasticsearchClient.bulk(bulkRequest);
            System.out.println("print " + result.ingestTook());
            if (result.errors()) {
                System.out.println("Bulk had errors");
                for (BulkResponseItem item: result.items()) {
                    if (item.error() != null) {
                        System.out.println(item.error().reason());
                    }
                }
            }
            return productFlux;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Flux.error(e);
        }
    });
}
```

This version of the `saveAll` method is using the `collectList` method to buffer all the elements of the `Flux` into a `List`, then using the `flatMap` method to transform the `List` into a `BulkRequest`. The `flatMap` method is also used to send the `BulkRequest` to Elasticsearch and handle the response.

Please note that this is a simplified example and it assumes that the number of elements in the `Flux` is small enough to fit into memory. If the `Flux` can have a large number of elements, you might want to consider using the `buffer` method to split the `Flux` into smaller chunks and process each chunk separately.

Also, note that the Elasticsearch [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/indexing-bulk.html#_indexing_application_objects) is designed to be used with a large number of requests. If you are only sending a few requests at a time, you might not see any performance benefit from using the bulk API.

Problem: this version still returns the original `Flux` after sending the `BulkRequest`, and it doesn't ensure that the indexing operation is completed before the returned `Flux` is consumed.

---

Another more robust approach: you could try using `Flux.collectList()` to gather all the products into a list, and then send this list to Elasticsearch using the [bulk API](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.8.0/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/core/bulk/package-summary.html). However, keep in mind that this would also accumulate all the data in memory before sending it, which might not be what you want if the `Flux` contains a lot of elements.

That would use a `Mono` this time:

```java
private Mono<Void> saveAll(Flux<Product> productFlux) {
    return productFlux.collectList().flatMap(products -> {
        BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();
        for (Product product : products) {
            br.operations(op -> op
                    .index(idx -> idx
                            .index("products")
                            .document(product)
                    )
            );
        }
        return elasticsearchClient.bulk(br.build()).then();
    });
}
```

The `flatMap()` operator is used to perform the asynchronous bulk operation for each list of products. The `then()` operator is used to transform the `Mono<BulkResponse>` returned by `elasticsearchClient.bulk(br.build())` into a `Mono<Void>`, effectively "ignoring" the `BulkResponse`. This allows the method to return only when all products have been sent to Elasticsearch.

The `saveAll()` method now returns a `Mono<Void>`, which represents the completion of the bulk indexing operation. You can use this to ensure that further processing only happens after all products have been indexed:

```java
Flux<Product> productFlux = ...;
Mono<Void> saved = saveAll(productFlux);
Flux<CompletedProduct> completedProductFlux = saved.thenMany(productFlux.map(this::toOneCompletedProduct));
completedProductFlux.subscribe();
```

`Mono.thenMany()` is used to create a new `Flux<CompletedProduct>` that will start emitting items only after the `saveAll()` operation has completed.

As you see in this second approach, `saveAll()` now returns a [`Mono<Void>`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) instead of a [`Flux<Product>`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) because the operation of indexing all products to Elasticsearch is a single, asynchronous operation that either completes or fails. This is exactly what a `Mono` represents: a single, asynchronous computation. The `Void` type parameter indicates that the `Mono` does not emit any value upon completion. It only signals the completion or failure of the operation.

In contrast, a `Flux` represents a sequence of zero or more items, and is used for operations that can produce multiple results over time.

When `saveAll()` was returning a `Flux<Product>`, it was actually just returning the original `Flux` passed to it. This didn't reflect the fact that all products have been indexed to Elasticsearch. It was possible for the returned `Flux` to be consumed *before* the indexing operation was completed, which could lead to unexpected behavior.

By returning a `Mono<Void>`, `saveAll()` now correctly represents the operation it performs: a single, asynchronous indexing operation that either completes or fails. The caller can use the returned `Mono` to chain further processing that should happen after the indexing operation is completed, as shown in the previous example.

Then end result (as a simplified example):

```java
@Service
public final class SomeService implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient;

    @Override
    public void run(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Flux<Product> productFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).map(i -> new Product(LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC), String.valueOf(i)));
        Mono<Void> saveOperation = saveAll(productFlux);
        Flux<CompletedProduct> completedProductFlux = saveOperation.thenMany(productFlux.map(this::toOneCompletedProduct));
        completedProductFlux.subscribe();
    }

    private Mono<Void> saveAll(Flux<Product> productFlux) {
        return productFlux.collectList().flatMap(products -> {
            BulkRequest.Builder br = new BulkRequest.Builder();
            for (Product product : products) {
                br.operations(op -> op
                        .index(idx -> idx
                                .index("products")
                                .document(product)
                        )
                );
            }
            return Mono.just(br.build());
        }).flatMap(bulkRequest -> {
            try {
                BulkResponse result = elasticsearchClient.bulk(bulkRequest);
                System.out.println("print " + result.ingestTook());
                if (result.errors()) {
                    System.out.println("Bulk had errors");
                    for (BulkResponseItem item: result.items()) {
                        if (item.error() != null) {
                            System.out.println(item.error().reason());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return Mono.empty();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return Mono.error(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private CompletedProduct toOneCompletedProduct(Product oneSavedProduct) {
        return // transform a product to a completed product AFTER saving to elasticsearch;
    }
}
```

You have:

- The `run()` method creates a `Flux<Product>`, calls `saveAll()` to save all products to Elasticsearch, and then uses the returned `Mono<Void>` to create a `Flux<CompletedProduct>` that starts emitting items only after the save operation is completed.
- The `saveAll()` method collects all products into a `List`, creates a `BulkRequest` for them, sends the `BulkRequest` to Elasticsearch, and returns a `Mono<Void>` that represents the completion of this operation.
- The `toOneCompletedProduct()` method transforms a saved product into a completed product. This method is used after the save operation is completed, as indicated by the `thenMany()` operator in the `run()` method.

By "simplified example", I mean for instance that error handling is quite minimal in this example. In a real-world scenario, you might want to add more comprehensive error handling to deal with potential failures of the Elasticsearch operation.

Comment: Excellent writing. Upvote + accept + award. Thank you for this (hope you get it before it gets removed)

Comment: @PatPanda I did get it, thank you  What approach did you take?

Comment: actually, both approaches have issues. Because the call to elasticsearch itself, with the current elasticsearch-java client, which underlying uses apache http client, is blocking. Therefore, both solutions are not really working. With that said, I used both codes, processing of the flux itself is very fast and correct, but in elastic, only a couple of documents are getting created

Comment: But the code you proposed is very clean, easy to understand, well explained. I opened an issue on elasticsearch-java side, and crossing fingers one day, I can plug in your code

Comment: @PatPanda OK, thank you for this feedback. Do you have the link for your issue? (Is it [`elastic/elasticsearch-java` issue 542](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/542)?)

Comment: You are correct, what I am hoping is when they complete the feature, your code will work "like magic". But instead of waiting for the feature, I believe your solution is actually correct

Comment: Unfortunately, this code seems not behaving correctly. elasticsearch-java just released a new feature where we can change the underlying http client. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/pull/584 Therefore, I went to change from the apache http client (which is blocking) to a non blocking reactor netty http client. BLockhound tested, Blockhound would flag the apache http call blocking, while using reactor netty, it passes. Even with that, this code would only save the first batch inside elasticsearch

Comment: @PatPanda OK. Don't hesitate to post your own answer with the updated code when it is working better.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is using a regular Elasticsearch Client to make a bulk request to ES. When working with reactive code, we should use [Reactive Rest Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.reactiverestclient). `ReactiveRestClient` still requires a `BulkRequest`, but internally uses Reactive Web Client to post a bulk request and hence returns a `Mono<Response>`. So basic code should look like

```java
productFlux
  .buffer() //to create sufficient load for bulk
  .flatMap(productList-> {
    // serialize to BulkRequest & send to Reactiveclient
  });
```

There are other important considerations when doing this:

1. Each bulk request will get bound to single thread on ES side, as far as I understand its architecture. So, we need to choose the buffer such that our bulk request size is not too small or too big.
2. We need to control the rate at which we send the data. For example, if we simply subscribe our product flux with infinite demand (Default subscribers), then, we are likely to hit scenario where ES will reject our request because all its internal thread will be busy processing our previous requests. If we simply create a custom subscriber that creates demand of say 1 (or specific low number) then we will unnecessarily slow the indexing process. So, an alternative will be to create a back-pressure based on response from ES. We can do this by adding an operator like `delayWhen` in our pipe to exponentially delay when we get specific errors (like *rejected execution.*)
3. We should add retry operators for some intermittent network exception etc. We need to ensure that our publisher is able to handle retries. This is important when creating a Flux over HTTP or Kafka. If we use an operator like `flatMap`, it has internal buffers which allows retry operators downstream to work.